# Change Substring of filename recursively in mac os

Tags: bash, macos, operating-system, homebrew

I'm trying to change the substring of a filename where it is contained within several sub folders.  Currently I'm using rename with 'homebrew renaame' but am running into issues.

I'd like to change 'CorporateAssessments-' to 'CorporateAssessments'. Here is my current code:

```
for x in $(find . -name CorporateAssessments-\*); do
    rename 's/CorporateAssessments-/' *CorporateAssessments*
done
```

When running this I get this error "Substitution replacement not terminated at (eval 2) line 1." Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `rename` perl utility installed, you can use this `find + rename`:

```bash
find . -name 'CorporateAssessments[ -]*' -exec \
rename 's/(CorporateAssessments)[ -]/$1/' _ {} +
```

If you don't have `rename` utility installed then use this `find + mv`:

```bash
find . -name 'CorporateAssessments[ -]*' -exec \
bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//[ -]}"' _ {} +
```

Comment: @StephenSelvey: Did this work out?

Comment: got some stuff blocking me from really testing but seems good.  Might be a few days.

Comment: Hi, this worked thanks. Any chance you know what how to 'CorporateAssessments .eps' to CorporateAssessments.eps' as well?  Basically remove a space in the file name?

Comment: I have modified my command to remove both `-` and space from filename